# Ajax call doesn't respond, can anyone tell me where I'm wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**>  Font-end:**
As you can see in this section, I made a loop that returns me the product categories

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 categories">
                <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal cs-list py-2 py-sm-5">
                   <?php
                       
                  $cat_args = array(
                             'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                             'orderby' => 'name',
                             'order' => 'ASC',
                             'hide_empty' => true,
                               'exclude'=>array(1),
                               'option_all'=> 'All'
                             );
                             $categories=get_categories($cat_args);
                             ?>
                  <?php foreach( $categories as $cat ) : ?>
                  <li class="list-group-item cs-item select-realm font-poppins js-filter-item">
                       <span class="hb hb-sm">
                        <a  data-category='<?php echo $cat->term_id ;?>' href='<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>'  style='color:white;' ><i class="hexagon"><?php echo $cat->name ?></i></a>
                       </span>
                    </li>
                  <?php                                            
                endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

**> Front-end:** This section loop products of the selected category

```
<div class='js-filter'>            
      <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'ASC' ); 
             $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
             if($loop->have_posts()):
             while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush list-group-products">
              <li class="list-group-item select-blue-essence">
                 <div class="row in-list-text">
                    <div class="col-4 text-center font-poppins">
                        <span class="fw-bold"><?php the_title();?></span><br>
                      <span><?php the_content();?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 price-tag font-poppins fw-bold"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                   <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                   <?php endwhile; ?>
                   <?php endif; ?>
                 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
              </ul>
              </div>
```

> **Function.php**
> I register Ajax in the functions and I think there is a problem somewhere

```
function load_scripts(){

wp_enqueue_script('ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scriptAjax.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true);

wp_localize_script('ajax','wpAjax',
  array('ajaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))
  );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

**> Ajax.js** Please see this ajax call as well. He doesn't even send Bad Request

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".js-filter-item > a", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var category = $(this).data("category");

      $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: { action: "filter", category: category },
        type: "post",
        success: function (result) {
          $(".js-filter").html(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
          window.alert("FAIL!");
        },
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

> **Ajax Call Back**

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_ajax');

function filter_ajax(){
    $category=$_POST['category'];

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'ASC' ); 

    if(isset($category)){
      $args['category__in'] = array($category);
    }
             $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
             if($loop->have_posts()):
             while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush list-group-products">
              <li class="list-group-item select-blue-essence">
                 <div class="row in-list-text">
                    <div class="col-4 text-center font-poppins">
                        <span class="fw-bold"><?php the_title();?></span><br>
                      <span><?php the_content();?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 price-tag font-poppins fw-bold"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                   <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                   <?php endwhile; ?>
                   <?php endif; ?>
                 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
              </ul>



 <?php die();
}




?>
```

Comment: Is it triggering the ajax call?

Comment: I cannot see any code which would accept the action `filter` which you are passing.

Comment: Does not trigger and open as link

Comment: @bhanu I added the rest of the code

Comment: Is this solved?

Comment: Partially, the Ajax trigger works after changing class from <li> directly to <a>, but I don't get products of the selected category.. @Arman H

Comment: than probably problem with your query check again your query and category id passed.